# .NET equivalent of Qt Graphics View Framework?

Tags: .net, graphics, qgraphicsview

Is there a .NET (3.5+) library that has similar features as [Qt Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview.html)? The main features I need are:

- Allows to display multiple dynamic 2D graphical items
- Supports zooming, rotation
- Separates a scene from views and allows to work in scene coordinates (instead of pixels).
- Allows picking individual items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like [WPF](http://windowsclient.net/default.aspx).

Comment: Does WPF have a "scene" that can be rendered on multiple views?

Comment: It has a [`canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx). Different name, similar concept.